# document.getElementById() always returns null

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I think i spent over an hour searching for a solution to this but i couldn't find any. I was creating a chrome extension with manifest 3 but i have a problem on requiring DOM elements from the content-script indicated in the manifest.

manifest.json

```json
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "extension name",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "description",
    "icons": {},
    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["*://*.domain.com/*"],
        "js": ["main.js"]
      }
    ],
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "host_permissions": [
        "*://*.domain.com"
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "cookies",
        "activeTab"
    ]
}
```

main.js

```js
window.onload = function () {
    console.log('window loaded')

    const run = document.getElementById('run');

    console.log(run);
}
```

popup.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <script src="main.js" type="module"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="run">Restore</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

> const run = document.getElementById('run');
> This is always null.

I would like to know what i am doing wrong and i will appreciate your asnwers.

(I am testing this on microsoft edge by the way and all the files are in the main folder)

The question in favor of which this one has been closed does not meet what i am trying to do also because i am not using jquery

Comment: Put the script tag after body. When your script runs there is no dom initialized. That's why it's not finding the button. Or you can add `defer` to script tag.

Comment: @Erenn This is a browser extension, the script isn't in the HTML.

Comment: @Barmar Ok. I wanna keep this reputation score constant anyway.

Comment: @Erenn it is not working still returns null.

Comment: @iKingNinja Is there logs in the console? I actually dont know about the browser extensions. You can open the question again. It got closed mistakenly I believe.

Comment: This is what it logs

```
window loaded
null
```

Answer (score 0):

you are running the script first before the element render.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <body>
        <button id="run">Restore</button>
    </body>
    <script src="main.js" type="module"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Shouldn't putting it in `window.onload` solve that problem?

Comment: That is not working. Also it should work if i put it into the window.onload event.